# Wrong count in admin Grid when using GROUP BY clause in collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am trying to add a custom column in my custom grid in the admin panel. To add the custom column, I have used **LEFT JOIN** and **GROUP BY** in the collection which I get from the parent grid class.

After using **JOIN** and **GROUP BY** clauses, I am able to add the custom column in my grid, but the issue is that the GRID is now showing the wrong count of records always.

It is always showing 1 as count.

I have added the same column in another grid and it is working fine.

**Note:** I am not using UI component. Since the grid is coming from an extension's block files, I am using block PHP file to add my custom column.

[image: Wrong Count]

Please help.

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Comment: @amesh, I have posted my solution. Please check and hit upvote if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution.

Below is my approach to fixing the count:

Create or open **app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/ResourceModel/[ModelClassFolder]/Collection.php**

and paste code like below:

```
<?php

namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ResourceModel\[ModelClassFolder];

class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
{        
    public function getSelectCountSql() {
        $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
        $countSelect->reset(\Zend\Db\Sql\Select::GROUP);
        return $countSelect;
    }
}
```

**Note:** You need to change **Namespace**, **Module**, **ModelClassFolder** and the **class** after **`extends`**.

Comment: Mohit in which file you have added the group by field name? Please share the finame with path

Comment: @BanvariLal, file name is mentioned in my answer: **app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/ResourceModel/Collection.php**